# iOS: Firefox - How can I remove an “Available Device” listed in the “Send Tab” extension if it is not listed on accounts.firefox.com?

Tags: ios, firefox

I installed Firefox on my iOS device and logged into my Firefox (Sync) account. This gives me a new "Send Tab" extension that I can use in Safari to send an opened web page to my Firefox desktop installations.

Unfortunately I also have an unkown/old/outdated device listed in "Available Devices". Sending the tab to that device does nothing. So I want to remove it, as it has a very similar name to my real Firefox Desktop installation.

I already tried removing it via "Devices & apps" on accounts.firefox.com, but it is not listed there - only my expected devices show up there.

For now I fixed it by adding "(real!)" to my real Firefox Desktop device name which makes me not use the wrong one any more, but of course is only an ugly workaround.

How can I remove this device from the list?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: More or less. The "Send Tab" extension seems to be gone completely, I can only find a "Firefox" button that needs an additional click on "Send to Device" to get to the device list. Using this doesn't seem to to open the tab automatically, I had to sync manually on my desktop Firefox to "catch" the tab.